# Why won't Google Script's getFolderbyId accept variables without error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

This is my code, the point is to pass in a folder ID and have it log all occurrences of the given file name within that folder:

```
function SearchFiles(SourceID) 
{
  var source = DriveApp.getFolderById(SourceID);
  var searchFor ='title contains "Desired File Name"';
  var names =[];
  var Dates=[];
  var files = source.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while(files.hasNext()) 
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var date = file.getDateCreated();
    Dates.push(date);
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name);
  }

  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++)
  {
    Logger.log(names[i]);
    Logger.log(Dates[i]);
  }
}

SearchFiles("ID Here");
```

The problem is, when this code is run I get the error "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it." despite making sure the ID is correct and that I have the correct permissions. However, if I instead put the correct ID directly into the getFolderById function instead of the variable, it all works correctly without error. What is preventing me from using the variable?

Comment: The `getFolderById()` method requires the ID to be a string.  If the function is receiving an ID that is an integer, that could cause an error.  Check the data type:  `Logger.log('typeof SourceID: ' + typeof SourceID)` Add that line of code, run the code and then View the Logs.  If the SourceID variable is not a 'string' data type, that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which function are you running? I guess you are running the `SearchFiles` function when you click run. Call the `SearchFiles` function in another function and run that function as below:

```
function myFunction() {
  SearchFiles("Folder ID");
}

function SearchFiles(SourceID) 
{
  var source = DriveApp.getFolderById(SourceID);
  var searchFor ='title contains "Desired File Name"';
  var names =[];
  var Dates=[];
  var files = source.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while(files.hasNext()) 
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var date = file.getDateCreated();
    Dates.push(date);
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name);
  }

  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++)
  {
    Logger.log(names[i]);
    Logger.log(Dates[i]);
  }
}
```

Run `myFunction` and it should work as expected:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I guess I thought calling it down below would work for that, but I guess not.